# ActionScrip3 Removing objects properly

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection

I'm working on a fairly basic "shootem up" game using ActionScript 3. This is the first time I've programmed in AS3, and it's coming along decently. However, I have one issue that just keeps rearing it's head, which is objects trying to do things after they've been removed, or after their parent has been removed, which throws a null object reference since their parent no longer exists.

I think I'm just making a fundamental error in how I handle garbage collection. What is the "normal" way to:

1) Remove an object from a stage, for example when an enemy dies, how do I safely remove it in a way that won't cause null object references?

2) Clear and remove an object that has many children, for example the ShooterGame object that contains all of the other game objects, such as the player ship, UI, enemies, projectiles, and so on?

I know that there is a removeChild function, which I've tried to use, but it seems to cause more problems than it fixes. Is there some other method I need to be using to clean up unused objects?

I'm not posting code here because, to be honest, I don't even know which parts I'm doing wrong, and I don't want to spam a ton of code that's probably irrelevant anyways. If there are specific parts that you need to see, though, let me know and I'll do my best to provide them.

Thanks in advance for the help, and sorry if this is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to destroy the object make sure to:

- Remove it from the display list if it's a DisplayObject
- Remove all the listeners from it
- Remove all the references to the object - remove it from all the arrays you store it in
- Remove all the intervals that uses the object if you use any.
- Set the object to null

Only then it can be garbage collected.

Also, since you're making a shooting game, it would make sense to create all your objects before hand and deactivate the objects instead of destroying them and making new ones. It's called object pooling, look into that. It should improve the performance and allow the game to run on mobile devices.

Comment: 1) All of my objects extend Sprite. Are Sprites DisplayObjects? If so, how do I remove it from the display list?
2) I don't think I was removing all of the listeners properly. This may actually be the root of my current issues.
3) If I have an array that holds, for example, all enemies, do I need to manually go through and clear each entry, or an I just set the whole array to null?
4) I don't know what an interval is, so I assume I don't need to worry about this, at least yet.
5) Is this just as simple as setting the variable the object was assigned to to null or is there something else to do?

Comment: 1) Sprites extends DisplayObjects, so yes, they are. You remove them with removeChild() method. 2) Always make sure to remove your listeners properly :P Can't make a system that manages it? Just make a new function removeListeners() and inside remove all listeners of those objects. 3) Well, just make a loop that goes trough the array and checks if the object is null. If it is, splice() it from the array. 4) Never use intervals, use Timer 5) Yes, just write object = null to set it to null.

Comment: Thanks. There were a few more bugs to work out, but I ended up figuring them out (somehow my bullets stopped listening for REMOVED_FROM_STAGE at some point). Everything seems to be working just fine now even with multiple restarts. Now I can finally get back to adding features!

Comment: Are you sure that your last point is a *requirement* rather than *insurance*?

Comment: @MartyWallace, there is a proper way of doing things. Setting an object to null is not a requirement, but a good practice non the less. It is also written do to so in the Essential Action Script 3.0 book, the official book that teaches as3.
Correct me if I'm wrong - the garbage collector will still remove an object from memory if there are no references to it, but it makes it easier for the gc to do so if the object is null.
Also, making object a null makes an easier check if you're running trough an array, because calls to object properties would take more time (e.g. checking x,y vars).